# UITableViewDataSource Delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I created a new Master-Detail Application from Xcode template

I found that the main interface ( in this case BirdMasterViewController ) inherit from UITableViewController,
and UITableViewController conform to UITableViewDataSource protocol

so I can specify methods like

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}
```

But I did not find a set delegate to _dataSource variable on BirdMasterViewController, like

```
xxxxxx._dataSource = self; or setDataSource: self
```

to set _dataSource object

```
// to this
id <UITableViewDataSource>  _dataSource;
```

Why the delegation can run ?

Comment: Are you using default template with storyboard or xib?
I think maybe outlet connect to your viewController in storyboard or xib

Comment: Like you mentioned "UITableViewController conform to UITableViewDataSource protocol", thus, there is no need to explicitly set `dataSource` and `delegate` to `self`. If you add a UITableView to UIViewController, then you will need to set these two properties.

Answer (score 2):

Add delegate in your .h file and then use your delegate methods :

```
@interface BirdMasterViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

Comment: UIViewController already conform to UITableViewDataSource,
Because BirdMasterViewController inherit from UIViewController, we don't need to set <UITableViewDataSource> again.
I'm confused, why the delegation can run without even set the _dataSource object.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you also check out tableview frameworks such as the free Sensible TableView framework. Should make your tableview development lot easier.